# Does Facebook have a program that regularly checks their employees' (especially their content moderator teams) political involvements?

Tags: social-media, propaganda, espionage, fake-news

Recently, here in the Philippines, there's [news that Facebook took down](https://www.mercurynews.com/2020/09/28/philippine-president-complains-after-facebook-takes-down-fake-accounts/) an account/group/page of an organization named "Hands Off Our Children". This is an organization that fights for parents whose kids were [recruited or allegedly kidnapped](https://interaksyon.philstar.com/rumor-cop/2019/09/06/154269/league-parents-missing-children-communist-npa-rebels/) by militant groups (rebels, [NPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_People%27s_Army), or whatever. Forgive me, I'm still new to politics and still catching up on this subject). Why would anyone remove such cause? We'll obviously it speaks against a certain political party.

I believe these kind of things are also happening in other countries. **Is there a law that mandates these social media companies to regularly examine their people and make sure they have no political involvement?**

For example, I have found a **conspiracy** about an FB manager that might be "friends" with someone on a political party (I don't have to mention names and please note this is a conspiracy). More pages, groups, and posts of one side are being deleted more than the other. Not to mention, [Troll factories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_farm) are playing a big role now (which could also be done as an inside job, I believe).

One could say that the pages of a party, were deleted because of some violations. But if you play with VPN (To jump from countries to another & assuming you have knowledge to the politics of those countries), Clean your browsing cache and cookies (Attempting to make sure the feed tuning algorithm do not totally feed you according to your taste), and do some investigation yourself, you can objectively observe that the same rules do not consistently and equally apply to all. Even deleting of troll accounts doesn't seem free from bias.

Take policing of troll accounts for example. If we were able to determine and plot on a graph the population of trolls according to their political groupings, we would probably see a huge difference across the groups. Especially if we look at the troll birth rates (creation of account) and death rates (banned/deleted).

**Any legislative and programmatic solution to this apart from maybe a [public international law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_law) against troll factories (companies)?**

Comment: Do you want to know if there are such laws in the Phillipines, or in the US, or anywhere in the world?

Comment: Can I get the answer for the three you mentioned? But yeah, more importantly for me is Philippines

Comment: Reddit seems to handle the issue on Troll Farming since 2016 US election very well with their content moderator bots and human admins. I'm curious on how to get my ideas to Facebook and propose some things (As if my opinions matter , lol).

Comment: It's very unlikely that there are such laws, however one would expect that the companies themselves monitor how well their employees do their job.

Comment: That's disturbing that no one have spent time on rethinking how the internet have totally changed the gameplay in this life and attempt to write some kind of a public international law about to control false information. Social media algorithms and humans that contribute to the information traffic should be policed fairly.

Shoving biased/false information to humans (through these data manipulation) is no different from "rape" (raping our brains). Or actually it's worst than just that. Access and control to information is power. And right now we are just subjects  to power.

Answer (score 2):

### Question:

> Recently, here in the Philippines, there's news that Facebook took down an account/group/page of an organization named "Hands Off Our Children".  Is there a law that mandates these social media companies to regularly examine their people and make sure they have no political "puppets"?

---

### Answer:

The article you reference says facebook "dismantle a network of fake accounts that originated in China and the Philippines".

> [Philippine president complains after Facebook takes down fake accounts](https://www.mercurynews.com/2020/09/28/philippine-president-complains-after-facebook-takes-down-fake-accounts/)
> Facebook said the fake accounts were dismantled because they had engaged in “coordinated inauthentic behavior.”
>
> Platforms like Facebook have become political battlegrounds and have helped strengthen Duterte’s support base, having been instrumental in his election victory in 2016.

It's likely no human was involved in dismantling those accounts.  Most fake  accounts are disabled by AI algorithms which seek out such accounts based on factors automated systems are best at determining.  Thus the "fake accounts" registered by users who didn't exist was more deterministic to facebooks actions than was the ideology being expressed or denograted.

Facebook is a company valued at more than $200 billion dollars and what they sell is the ability to manipulate and change the behaviors on a small scale of the people who spend time on their site.  It likely wasn't that facebook cared about the ideology which was being espoused and more likely they objected to China and the Philippines trying to bypass their corporate profits and manipulate/inform their corporate assets(users) directly independent of facebook's monetization model.

I'm sure if the Philippines and China are willing to pay for the access, not only will the effectiveness of their messages dramatically increase, but they will have no additional troubles from Facebook dismantling their accounts.

Comment: So the best a country could do is pay Facebook? Damn, sad. Totally makes sense. Understandable but unacceptable though.